Electron Forge app starts up a local server on startup but generates multiple windows
I've created an Electron Forge App that wraps a React app but also should start a node.js local server when open. This works well when I run the app using npm start but when I run npm run make, the .exe file that's created generates multiple windows in a loop. I can't find the error, this is the code on main.js where I start the server:
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('node:path');
const { fork } = require('child_process');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

let serverProcess;

const startServer = () => {
  serverProcess = fork(path.join(__dirname, '../../src/server/index.js'));
};

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  startServer();
  createWindow();

  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// Quit the server process when the Electron app is quitting
app.on('before-quit', () => {
  if (serverProcess) {
    serverProcess.kill();
  }
});


I've tried using chatGPT but this issue continues
